# Create a date range in julian date python

Tags: python, pandas, astropy

I have to create a range between two dates, interval between dates of some minutes, in Julian date, i create a code, but is taking a lot of time about(15 minutes, for the ex.)

my code is:

```
from astropy.time import Time
import pandas as pd    
timedelta = "600s"
start = "2018-01-01" 
end = "2018-06-30"
dateslist = pd.date_range(start,end, freq =timedelta  ).tolist()
dates =  pd.DataFrame({'col':dateslist})
dates["col2"] =""
for i in range(len(dateslist)):
    #print(i," / ", len(dateslist))
    dates["col2"][i] = (Time(str(dateslist[i]).replace(" ", "T"), format="fits").jd)
```

I tried using Time without for, but is getting  error

```
time = str(list(dates['col'])).replace("[Timestamp('","").replace(" Timestamp('","").replace("')","").replace(" ","T").split(",")
time
Time(time, format="fits")
```

> ValueError: Input values did not match the format class fits

Is there some way of doing this quickly?

Thanks for now,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.to_julian_date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_julian_date.html):

```
dates["col2"] = pd.date_range(start,end, freq = timedelta).to_julian_date()
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent way in astropy would be:

```
from astropy.time import Time
import astropy.units as u
timedelta = 600 * u.s
start = "2018-01-01" 
end = "2018-06-30"
dates["col2"] = np.arange(Time(start).jd, Time(end).jd, timedelta.to_value('day'))
```

An alternate (perhaps more idiomatic way in astropy) is:

```
start = Time("2018-01-01")
end = Time("2018-06-30")
timedelta = 600 * u.s
dates = start + timedelta * np.arange((end - start) / timedelta)
```

This gives you a vector `Time` object, which you could convert to JD via the `jd` attribute.